# Driver to connect database to java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, netbeans

I have a problem

I want to get data from a graphical interface and save them on a `SQL` file on `Netbeans` 
and then import from `SQL` to fill the graphical interface.

I have my database ready but the only

**Problem:**

I have  *how to get to the SQL from java*, and I tried the code, then I got an `Exception`

```
ClassNotFoundException: myDriver.ClassName
SQLException: No suitable driver found for Jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample[app on APP]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the connector jar of the database to the classpath of your project, as stated in other answers.

With Derby, that jar is the same one that runs the database. [Explanation of how to add a jar to the classpath in Netbeans.](http://javahowto.blogspot.co.uk/2006/06/set-classpath-in-eclipse-and-netbeans.html)

Comment: i know im trying to find out what library to add (JDBC)

Comment: @remiyazigi: The library that you need to add is the derby.jar in the lib directory of the file you did download from the site. Is the only one required by this database.

Answer (score 1):

For the oracle database you need to add oracle library for the datatbase connection.
oracle library is available in the path of where you installed the oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the database jar in your classpath depending on which database you are using. Here is tutorial to help you understand about creating JDBC connection:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html#drivermanager

Answer (score 0):

if you using oracle database means You should add the oracle library file  in the Netbeans..
[check here](https://www.classle.net/faq/i-need-configure-oracle-10g-netbeans#)